# How to get selected text of text widget on verify listener event verifyText(...)

Tags: java, swt

I have a text widget that contains a numeric value representaion for a port (TCP). I validate the value, because the maximum port size is 65535.

Problem:
The field initially contains the value 8001. Now, if the user doublclicks the text widget, the whole text will be selected. The wants to enter a new port like 7002.

For the validation On VerifyListener's - verifyText method i use the current value of the text widget (8001) and the typed in char (7).

-> 80017 is invalid

```java
textField.addVerifyListener(new VerifyListener() {

    @Override
    public void verifyText(VerifyEvent e) {
        String text = ((Text) e.widget).getText();
        try {
           if(Integer.parseInt(text+e.character) > 65535) {

                   MessageBox.openError( composite.getShell(), 
                   "Invalid value", 
                   "Invalid value" );

                   e.doit = false;

           }
        } catch (Exception e2) {/*ignore*/}
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i did it. :)

```java
textField.addVerifyListener(new VerifyListener() {

    @Override
    public void verifyText(VerifyEvent e) {
        String text = ((Text) e.widget).getText();
        try {
           /*-------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
           String newText = text.substring(0, e.start) + e.text + text.substring(e.end);
           /*-------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
           if(Integer.parseInt(newText) > 65535) {

                   MessageBox.openError( composite.getShell(), 
                   "Invalid value", 
                   "Invalid value" );

                   e.doit = false;

           }
        } catch (Exception e2) {/*ignore*/}
    }
});
```

Comment: If the text is not an integer `parseInt` will throw `NumberFormatException` - you might want to show an error for that as well.